# String replacement in bash script giving error

Tags: linux, string, bash, shell

I am trying to replace a particular character in string using bash script but I am failing.

I have following code

```
    line=${array[1]}
    echo ${array[1]}
    echo ${array[0]}
    echo `expr index "$line" *`
```

The line or array[1] contains following string `/path/v1/module/order/*` and I want to replace `*` with some input value from another file.

But i got error at last line ... I tried with line variable and even with array. The error was 
`expr: syntax error`

P.S: I am using bash version 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just using bash [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)

```
line='/path/v1/module/order/*'
repl='some other value'
newvalue=${line/\*/$repl}
echo "$newvalue"
```

```
/path/v1/module/order/some other value
```

Answer (score 1):

The unquoted asterisk is expanded to a list of file names before `expr` is called. Use

```
echo $( expr index "$line" "*" )
```

(The `$(...)` is not necessary, but recommended in place of backquotes.)